# How do I enable automatically nvidia-uvm?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda, opencl, darktable

in order to use darktable with OpenCL everytime before starting darktable I have to issue

```
sudo modprobe nvidia-uvm
sudo mknod -m 666 /dev/nvidia-uvm c 250 0
```

What is the right way to enable nvidia-uvm by default?

Regards,
Oliver

Answer (score 6):

Proper way to do this is described in CUDA documentation:
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#runfile-verifications

Script from link above:

```
#!/bin/bash

/sbin/modprobe nvidia

if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
  # Count the number of NVIDIA controllers found.
  NVDEVS=`lspci | grep -i NVIDIA`
  N3D=`echo "$NVDEVS" | grep "3D controller" | wc -l`
  NVGA=`echo "$NVDEVS" | grep "VGA compatible controller" | wc -l`

  N=`expr $N3D + $NVGA - 1`
  for i in `seq 0 $N`; do
    mknod -m 666 /dev/nvidia$i c 195 $i
  done

  mknod -m 666 /dev/nvidiactl c 195 255

else
  exit 1
fi

/sbin/modprobe nvidia-uvm

if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
  # Find out the major device number used by the nvidia-uvm driver
  D=`grep nvidia-uvm /proc/devices | awk '{print $1}'`

  mknod -m 666 /dev/nvidia-uvm c $D 0
else
  exit 1
fi
```